# dropdown value change according to radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is task in which when i select "12 hour" radio button then drop down value change in 1 am-12 am and 1 pm-12 pm and when i select 24 hours then my value change in 1-24.

My code is:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var listA = [{name:'1am', value:'1am'}, {name:'2am', value:'2am'}, {name:'3am', value:'3am'}];

  var listB = [{name:'12', value:'12'}, {name:'13', value:'13'}, {name:'14', value:'14'}];
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(':radio').bind('click',function(){
      $('#describe')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end();
      $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
        $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Html code for this:

```
<div>
  <select id="describe">
    <option name="name" value="1">a</option>
    <option name="name" value="2">b</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="class" name="type" value="1" checked>12 hour <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="Club" name="type" value="2" >24 hour<br/>
</div>
```

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: please provide fiddle whenever possible, it is easy to test & update there

Comment: change value according radio button.when you click on radio button 1 then drop down have different value and if u select drop down 2 then drop down value is different  .drop down is single.

Comment: sorry i am enable to provide fiddle :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
<script>
  var listA = [{name:'1am', value:'1am'}, {name:'2am', value:'2am'}, {name:'3am', value:'3am'}];
  var listB = [{name:'12', value:'12'}, {name:'13', value:'13'}, {name:'14', value:'14'}];
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#class').bind('click', function() {
      $('#describe').empty();                              
      $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
        $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
      });
    });

    $('#Club').bind('click', function(){
      $('#describe').empty();                              
      $.each(listB, function(index, value) {
        $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: change  $('#class).bind('c to  $('#class').bind('c

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<div>
  <select id="describe">
    <option name="name" value="1">a</option>
    <option name="name" value="2">b</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="class" name="chk" value="12" checked>12 hour <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="Club" name="chk" value="24" >24 hour<br/>
</div>
```

Script

```
var listA = [{name:'1am', value:'1am'}, {name:'2am', value:'2am'}, {name:'3am', value:'3am'}];

 var listB = [{name:'12', value:'12'}, {name:'13', value:'13'}, {name:'14', value:'14'}];

  $(document).ready( function() {
      $("input[name='chk']").on('change',function() {

          if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '12')
          {
            $('#describe').empty()
            $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
             $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
            });                  
          }
          else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '24')
          {
            $('#describe').empty()
            $.each(listB, function(index, value) {
             $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
            }); 
          }
          else
          {

          }

    });
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/259/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#describe').val($(this).val());
```

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change only 3 lines of your existing code

First combine two list in one, like this

```
var list = [ 
  [{name:'1am', value:'1am'}, {name:'2am', value:'2am'}, {name:'3am', value:'3am'}],
  [{name:'12', value:'12'}, {name:'13', value:'13'}, {name:'14', value:'14'}]
];
```

then in radio click event, get radio button index, like this

```
  var index = $(this).val()-1;
```

then change your list with above list, like this

```
   $(document).ready( function() {
      $("input[type='radio']").on('change',function() {
          var index = $(this).val()-1;
          $('#describe').empty()
          $.each(list[index], function(index, value) {
           $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');  
          });
      });
});
```

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color